# How to find the basis for an intersection of 2 subspaces U,V in $\mathbb{R}{^5}$ , dim(V)=dim(U)=2?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The basis for U is
$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0  \\ 0 & 0  \\ -1 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
The basis for V is
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2  \\ 1 & 2  \\ 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 5\\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$$

I need to find a basis for U$\cap$V , but my result is in  $\mathbb{R}{^4}$ , I know that the dim(U$\cap$V)=1. I can't figure out how to find fifth dimension as the matrix made up by
$$\begin{pmatrix} U & | & -V \end{pmatrix}$$
has only 4 columns.

What's the correct way of finding all the unknowns when the number of columns < number of unknowns ?

Comment: Why are you working with $(U \mid -V)$?  You want an intersection.  Are those four basis vectors linearly independent?

Comment: once you have found the kernel of that matrix, that is in $R^4$, cut the last two entries and multiply it again by $U$ on the left

Comment: One approach is to use the [Zassenhaus algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zassenhaus_algorithm)

Comment: @EricTowers I use the method from this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9dlGmSaAWFU&t=266s , is there another way? Maybe better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is as follows. Let $\{u_1,u_2\}$ denote the given basis for $U$, and let $\{v_1,v_2\}$ denote the given basis for $V$. We can compute the reduced row echelon form
$$
\pmatrix{u_1&u_2&v_1&v_2} \leadsto \left(\begin{array}{cccc} 1 & 0 & 0 & 3\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & -3\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 2\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array}\right).
$$
This tells us that the first three columns are linearly independent, but the four vectors satisfy the relation
$$
v_2 = 3u_1 - 3u_2 + 2v_1.
$$
Rearranging this equation, we have $3u_1 - 3u_2 = -2v_1 + v_2$. In other words, the vector $-2v_1 + v_2 = (0,0,0,3,-3)$ is an element of both $U$ and $V$, and is thus an element of the intersection of $U$ and $V$. As you have noted, $\dim (U \cap V) = 1$, so the set $\{(0,0,0,3,-3)\}$ is a basis for $U \cap V$.

---

In light of the details of the question, note that the same reasoning can be applied if we instead consider the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{u_1&u_2&-v_1&-v_2} \leadsto \left(\begin{array}{cccc} 1 & 0 & 0 & -3\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 3\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 2\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array}\right).
$$